# CentOS Elastix Two Routes In Linux

Tags: linux, centos, asterisk, voip, elastix

Have the next problem in my LINUX ASTERISK ELASTIX SERVER

Have two interfacaces:

eth0:
inet addr:192.168.1.240  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1:
inet addr:10.7.227.110  Bcast:10.7.227.111  Mask:255.255.255.252

The eth0 is the Internet and SIP Phones Network
The eth1 is the TRUNK of the TELMEX PROVIDIER

If make route show:

[root@localhost ~]# /sbin/route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

10.7.227.108    *               255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eth1

192.168.1.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0

192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1

default         10.7.227.109    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1

The problem:

The server dont connect to internet, if traceroute all time out by the eth1

DONT WORK TO MY INTERNET GATEWAY OR ANY OTHER PUBLIC IP

[root@localhost ~]# traceroute 192.168.1.1

traceroute to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets

1  * * *

2  * * *

WORK TO INTERNAL TELMEX IP

[root@localhost ~]# traceroute 10.7.224.1

traceroute to 10.7.224.1 (10.7.224.1), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets

1   (10.7.227.109)  0.886 ms  1.119 ms  1.428 ms

2   (10.170.40.1)  0.611 ms  0.617 ms  0.850 ms

3   (10.7.224.12)  1.993 ms  1.994 ms  1.990 ms

If delete the Route eth1, the calls dont out, but have internet,

Can you help me please?
Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your internet interface is eth0, then you have to remove `default 10.7.227.109 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth1` from a route table.
And add eth0 with its gateway as default.

Comment: No, because if remove eth1 the the sip trunk don't can connect with the IP 10.7.224.1 ( the telmex server) and to this server only can access by the eth1 this is my problem....

Comment: Change the route, don't remove the interface.
Because eth1 and 10.7.224.1 are in the same subnet, your server doesn't need a default route to connect to it. But if you want to access an internet via eth0, you have to configure a default route at it.